# Workflow doesn't get triggered on prerelease

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub Actions workflow for a repo on my GitHub account which creates a release:

```yaml
- name: Create Release
  id: create_release
  uses: actions/create-release@v1
  env:
  GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}  
  with:
  tag_name: Release Dev
  release_name: Release Number
  body: Release is published
  draft: false
  prerelease: true
  prerelease: false
```

and another workflow is triggered on prerelease creation:

```
on:
  release:
    types: [prereleased]
```

There is a release created on GitHub, so the first workflow action works properly. Why is the second workflow not triggered?

The second workflow should be triggered immediately after the release creation, but that is not happening.

Comment: Events from actions taken with the [automatic token authentication](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication) explicitly do not trigger new workflows.

Answer (score 0):

I found the Solution

1. need to create Secret for the repository - I give it name **PAT**
   [Creating Secret for a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions#creating-secrets-for-a-repository)
2. I changed GitHub Token to new Secret

```
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.PAT }}
```